# Do you have to include .PSB's when handing over master .psd ?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I'm handing over a master.psd for a website, but inside I have a link to a smart object which seems to be a .PSB file.

If i just hand over the one master.PSD is this .PSB file embedded inside of it..or will the person I'm handing it over to have a File not found or accessible when he double clicks on the .PSB layer Smart Object ? 
thanks

Comment: Smart Objects (PSBs) are embedded, as far as I've always noticed in my own works.

Comment: my experience is that placed objects are not "live" in that when you edit the source, the psd files object is not updated/is unaware of the edit. this implies that it is actually embedded in the psd.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. [Linked Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html#createlinkedsmartobjects) were added in Photoshop CC 2014, which are not embedded in the PSD. Embedded Smart Objects are, as the name suggests, embedded in the PSD.

You can tell what kind of Smart Object you have by the icon in the layer thumbnail:

[image: Photoshop Smart Objects]

If you do have Linked Smart Objects you can package all linked files and a copy of the PSD to a folder of your choice by going to **File → Package**.